# How to use pydeps to produce a diagram showing functions dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies

I have a small project which I want to depict the dependencies between the functions.

I tried using pydeps for this but when I do that I get a, very nice, diagram of the modules in the project but not how the functions interact.

This is how I invoke pydeps ...

```
pydeps --include-missing --show-deps --max-bacon 4 ./test/
```

Inside of `./test` I have a set of python modules including an `__init__.py`.

I'm not even 100% sure that functional dependency depiction is what pydeps is meant to do ... the documentation only shows links between modules.

Can pydeps do this ? If not can something else do it ?

---

**Things I've tried**

- I tried **pycallgraph** . Although I installed it in a pipenv environment I couldn't follow the directions without installing it using apt-get. When I then try to use it it complains it can't find 'pandas' which is installed within the pipenv environment but clearly not visible. I don't want to install pandas globally (which I assume would resolve this issue).
- Tried **pyan3** and got the message `__init__() got multiple values for argument 'root'`... which I wasn't sure how to interpret but is referenced here https://github.com/Technologicat/pyan/issues/64 without any useful resolution.